# Exclude between time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know that you can select data from [pandas.DatetimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) using [pandas.DataFrame.between_time](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html). Is there a convenient way to exclude between two times in `pandas`?

For example, to exclude data between 16:00 and 17:00, I am currently doing the following.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(24 * 60 + 1, 2), columns=list("AB"), index=pd.date_range(start="20161013 00:00:00", freq="1T", periods=24 * 60 +1))

In [3]: idx = df.index.hour == 16

In [4]: df = df[~idx]

In [5]: df.between_time("16:00", "17:00")
Out[5]: 
                            A         B
2016-10-13 17:00:00 -0.745892  1.832912
```

**EDIT**

I have been able to use this:

```
In[41]:df2 = df.ix[np.setdiff1d(df.index, df.between_time("16:00", "17:00").index)]


In[42]:df2.between_time("15:59", "17:01")
Out[42]: 
                            A         B
2016-10-13 15:59:00  1.190678  0.783776
2016-10-13 17:01:00 -0.590931 -1.059962
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Sounds like a bug

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine `between_time` with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df2 = df.drop(df.between_time("16:00", "17:00").index)
```

**Edit**

An alternate method is to exploit the fact that `between_time` operates circularly, so you can switch the order of your input times to exclude the range between them:

```
df.between_time("17:00", "16:00", include_start=False, include_end=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['hour'] = df.index.hour
df[(df['hour'] < 16) | (df['hour'] > 17)]
```

Comment: I understand that we can do this `df.ix[(df.index.hour > 16) | (df.index.hour < 17)]` even, without using an extra column, but I am looking for a general solution between any two times. This breaks down if you want data excluding let's say 16:23 and 16:53:52.

Comment: I answered the specific problem that was originally there, but you're right. You could create a custom function to do the filtering for you. Consider a function called `filtWithin` that takes a timestamp, a start time and an endtime and returns True whenever the timestamp is outside that window. Then you could do this  `df[df.apply(lambda x: filtWithin(x.index, 12, startTime, endTime), axis=1)]`